# Remove 3 dots from antd horizontal scroll with collapse menu and add arrow button with horizontal scroll

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

Problem Statement - Hi guys i have implemented antd menu for the scrolling the tab horizontally and it is also responsive in mobile view but the problem is in the mobile view as per the screen resolution some of the tabs are getting showed, and at the end 3 dots are coming and hovering on that 3 dots menu is collapsing and and remaining tabs are coming, so i want arrow button instead of 3 dots and onclick of arrow button it should not be open collapse menu instead it should scroll the tabs horizontally, so please help to achieve this.

```html
<Menu
  defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
  defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
  mode="horizontal"
  theme="light"
  onClick={(e) => onMenuClicked(e)}
>
  <Menu.Item key="1">Characters</Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="3">Objects</Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="2">Emotions</Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="4">Audio</Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="8">Activity</Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="6">Location</Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="7">Moderations</Menu.Item>
  <Menu.Item key="5">Tags</Menu.Item>
</Menu>
```

Image Attached:

- The image is showing the issue which i dont want.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IgnK.png
- The image is showing the arrow button.
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIord.png

Comment: Please take a look at the [api documentation](https://ant.design/components/menu#api) there is a `overflowedIndicator` which should be the thing you need

Comment: Through the api doc i am able changed the icon that i changed now, but the issue is onclick of that icon i want to scroll right instead of collapse menu open as i mentioned in the above image refer first image how i can achieve that

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to bring back the arrows since antd 5 version if you want them you should use 4.x version they might bring the arrows functionality back if there will be a demand for it

every one who needs it pls report here so they will see the demand
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/44520